# Copy contents of a class member vector into another vector and then swapping them back

Tags: c++, class, vector, member

So I have two classes in the following format:

```
class HashMinHeap {
private:
    vector<int> MiniHeap;
public:
  ...
];

class HashTable {
private:
    vector<HashMinHeap*> table;

public:
...
};
```

I want to create a second vector, `vector <HashMinHeap*> table2`, copy the contents of `table` into `table2`, then I'm going to do some operations onto `table` that will eventually remove the contents of `table`, so to preserve it's content I want swap back the original contents from`table2`back into `table`.  Anyone know how to do the copying and swapping?
Thanks!
**NOTE** `table` has `HashMinHeap`objects in it when I do the copying and swapping.

Comment: Don't get it. You want to do some funky mutable operations on your vector, but don't want to loose it's content? Why not just copy it and do the mutable operations on the copy? Also, when you copy a `vector of pointers`, be aware that the vector is only going to do a shallow copy. In other words, the copy is still going to point to the same pointers (the same `HashMinHeap` objects).

Comment: How do I properly make the copy so that the mutable operations on the copy won't destroy the original?

Comment: Why do you use `vector to pointers`? Why not just `vector<HashMinHeap> table`? In which case, a full copy of that vector is as simple as `vector<HashMinHeap> myFullCopy = table;`. There might be a good reason why you do use `vector to pointers`, and it would be great if you could explain that. The other thing that is very unclear to me is why you'd copy some object, modify it, and then throw it away? What is the bigger problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I wanted a way to keep track of empty slots in the vector by having the slots pointing to NULL. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: My task was to create a hash table with separate chaining for collision result. However, the chaining must be a min-heap implementation. I already have a function,deleteMin, that finds the smallest element and then removes it from the data structure. Now I want to print all the elements in increasing order so I want to reuse my deleteMin function but also preserve the contents of the data structure.

Comment: Instead of 'chatting' via comments, see my answer regarding deep-copy. The concerns regarding the usage of pointers and the copy-modify-then-throw-away cumbersomeness, please update your question with a working http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On the question "How to deep clone a `vector of pointers`"**

Use a copy constructor as demonstrated below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class HashMinHeap {
public:
    string s;
    vector<int> MiniHeap;

    HashMinHeap() { }

    HashMinHeap(const HashMinHeap& other ) : MiniHeap(other.MiniHeap), s(other.s) { }
};

class HashTable {
public:
    vector<HashMinHeap*> table;

    HashTable() { }

    HashTable(const HashTable& other ) {
        for(auto& item : other.table) {
            table.push_back(new HashMinHeap(*item));
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    HashTable table;
    table.table.push_back(new HashMinHeap);
    table.table.push_back(new HashMinHeap);
    table.table[0]->s = "Hello world....";
    table.table[1]->s = "Hello universe....";

    HashTable tableCopy = table;
    tableCopy.table[0]->s = "Changed....";

    cout << "original1 " << table.table[0]->s << endl;
    cout << "original2 " << table.table[1]->s << endl;
    cout << "copy " << tableCopy.table[0]->s << endl;
    cout << "copy2 " << tableCopy.table[1]->s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Results

```
original1 Hello world....
original2 Hello universe....
copy Changed....
copy2 Hello universe....
```